# what is IWebBrowser::Navigate2 equivalent for window.open(...)?

Tags: c#, c++, com

i need equivalent for

window.open('url to open','window name','toolbar=no');

in c#, or C++ - no metter

Thanks for any help

Comment: Wouldn't you have to create the new window with a new navigator control yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use [IHTMLWindow2::open](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa741489%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

```
BOOL OpenWindow(IWebBrowser2* pWebBrowser, CString strUrl, CString strName, CString strFeatures)
{
    if(pWebBrowser != NULL)
    {
        CComDispatchDriver pDocDisp;
        if(SUCCEEDED(pWebBrowser->get_Document(&pDocDisp)))
        {   
            CComQIPtr<IHTMLDocument2> pDoc = pDocDisp;
            if(pDoc != NULL)
            {
                CComPtr<IHTMLWindow2> pWindow;
                if(SUCCEEDED(pDoc->get_parentWindow(&pWindow)))
                {
                    CComPtr<IHTMLWindow2> pWindowResult;
                    return SUCCEEDED(pWindow->open(CComBSTR(strUrl), CComBSTR(strName), CComBSTR(strFeatures), VARIANT_FALSE, &pWindowResult));
                }
            }
        }           
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a pointer to the `IWebBrowser2` interface, you can call `IWebBrowser2::get_document` and retrieve the `IDispatch` interface. You can then query it for `IHTMLDocument2`. Once you have that call `IHtmlDocument2::get_parentWindow`. From the `IHTMLWindow2` interface that is returned you can call `IHTMLWindow2::execScript` and you can pass in your javascript directly to that function and have it executed.